# C++ equivalent of Rust enums

Tags: c++, enums

This example shows an elegant way to deal with messages of different types in Rust. It has 4 variants and some variants have sub members that are only accessible if the enum is of that specific type. A similar pattern is also possible in TypeScript.

```rust
enum Message {
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}
```

In C++ this would most likely compare to the following code.

```cpp
struct Message
{
    enum MessageType {QUIT, MOVE, WRITE, CHANGECOLOR} type;
    union MessageContent
    {
        struct Move { int x; int y;} move;
        std::string write;
        std::tuple<int, int, int> changeColor;
    } content;
};
```

However, this way isn't typesafe and memory management is going to become messy (e.g. making sure that string gets released if `Message` gets destructed if `MessageType` is `WRITE`). What is the best way to do this in modern C++?

Comment: I'm not sure C++ has a direct analog to that here, as the Rust version is significantly more capable than C++ is without serious hacking around.

Comment: Could you make a template class with varargs and somehow crush that into a structure that...works?

Answer (score 52):

This is what [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is for.

(Though note, since C++ does not have pattern matching, using variants is still rather cumbersome compared to languages like Rust.)

Using `std::variant`, your example would look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xcjdvs):

```
struct Quit {};
struct Move { int32_t x; int32_t y; };
struct Write { std::string s; };
struct ChangeColor { int32_t r; int32_t g; int32_t b; };
using Message = std::variant<Quit, Move, Write, ChangeColor>;
```

The closest thing to Rust's `match` expressions is [`std::visit`](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/09/visit-variants.html).  Visiting this example variant could look like:

```
// Utility to allow overloading lambdas for use in std::visit
template<class... Ts>
struct overload : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};
template<class... Ts>
overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

int main() {
    auto visitor = overload{
        [](const Quit& q)        { std::cout << "Quit\n"; },
        [](const Move& m)        { std::cout << "Move " << m.x << " " << m.y << "\n"; },
        [](const Write& w)       { std::cout << "Write " << w.s << "\n"; },
        [](const ChangeColor& c) { std::cout << "ChangeColor " << c.r << " " << c.g << " " << c.b << "\n"; }
    };

    Message m1{Quit{}};
    Message m2{Move{1, 2}};
    Message m3{Write{"a"}};
    Message m4{ChangeColor{1, 2, 3}};
    std::visit(visitor, m1);
    std::visit(visitor, m2);
    std::visit(visitor, m3);
    std::visit(visitor, m4);
}
// This prints:
//   Quit
//   Move 1 2
//   Write a
//   ChangeColor 1 2 3
```

Comment: Maybe point out that `std::visit` is the way to handle different variants in C++ (unlike match in Rust). Always a good resource: https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/09/visit-variants.html

Comment: @Unapiedra Example added.

Comment: What is `overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;`?

Comment: @MaPo It is a common pattern used to define visitors in terms of a series of lambdas.  [This](https://arne-mertz.de/2018/05/overload-build-a-variant-visitor-on-the-fly/) blog post goes into some good detail.

Comment: @MaPo A template deduction guide. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by the answer of [0x5453](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282436/0x5453), I wrote a snippet to help the rust-style handling of `std::variant`:

```cpp
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

template <typename Val, typename... Ts>
auto match(Val &&val, Ts... ts) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{ts...}, std::forward<Val>(val));
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
match(value, [](Type1 type1) {
        ;
    },
    [](Type2 type2) {
        ;
    },
    ...
    [](TypeN typeN) {
        ;
    }
);
```

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

template <typename Val, typename... Ts>
auto match(Val &&val, Ts... ts) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{ts...}, std::forward<Val>(val));
}

class A {
public:
    A() : v_(0) {}
    A(int v) : v_(v) {
        std::cout << "Initializing " << V() << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A& a) : v_(a.v_) {
        std::cout << "Copying " << V() << std::endl; }
    A(A&& a) : v_(a.v_) {
        std::cout << "Moving " << V() << std::endl;
        a.Drop();
    }
    // Explicitly delete it just in case.
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&& a) {
        v_ = a.v_;
        a.Drop();
        std::cout << "Move assigning " << V() << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    ~A() {
        if (V()) {
            std::cout << "Deconstructing " << V() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    int V() { return v_; }
private:
    void Drop() {
        v_ = 0;
    }
    int v_;
};
auto func(bool choice) -> std::variant<A, int> {
    if (choice) {
        // Initializing 1
        return A(1);
        // Moving 1
    } else {
        return 233;
    }
};
auto main() -> int {
    A a;
    std::cout << match(func(true),
        [&](A&& ret) -> std::string {
            // Move assigning 1
            a = std::move(ret);
            return "A";
        },
        [&](int ret) -> std::string {
            a = A(ret);
            return "int";
        }
    ) << std::endl; // A
    // 1
    std::cout << a.V() << std::endl;

    return 0;
    // Deconstructing 1
}
```

Output:

```
Initializing 1
Moving 1
Move assigning 1
A
1
Deconstructing 1
```

References:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

https://polomack.eu/std-variant/

https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers